# How to stop a java class when undeploying a mule application

Tags: java, spring, class, mule, undeploy

My Mule application uses a java class which is started as a Spring Bean. This works fine. But I have a problem when I undeploy my application and deploy a newer version.

After I undeploy the application the java process is still active. After deploying the new version of the application, there are two instances of the java class running.

As a solution I have added a shutdown hook to the java class. The hook works, but only when I shutdown Mule itself. Not when I undeploy the app.

To test this I have done the following:

- Deploy application and undeploy it.
- Check in log for message of shutdown java process, nothing found.
- Deploy the application again.
- Stop Mule and check log. Now there are two entries about the shutdown of the java process.

What should I do to stop the java process when I undeploy the application?

Thanks,
Jeroen

I am using Mule 3.4.0 and jdk1.7.0_25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `stop` method on your class and call it via Spring's `destroy-method`.

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more?
Thank you.